# java.lang.StackOverflowError in Linked List?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm using BlueJay as my IDE.
My goal is to create a method that print each value in the list in a single line starting from head, separated by three spaces.

What I have so far is there and it produces no syntax errors in BlueJ:

```
public String toString(E val) {
         Node<E> node = head;
        Node<E> newNode= new Node<E>(val);
         String str = " ";
         if (!isEmpty()) {
         newNode.next = head;
         head= newNode;
        while ((head!= null)){
            str += toString(head.val);
            str += toString(head.val) + " " + " " + "  ";
           newNode = newNode.next;

        }
        return str;

        }
```

However, after altering it around when I try to test my code in Blue J using "inspect" and I enter a string. I just get "space" instead of the string that I typed in with three spaces.
I have a feeling that it has to do with

```
 my str = toString(head.val);
            str += toString(head.val) + " " + " " + "  ";
```

I was trying to concatenate strings but it didn't work. 
Any suggestions to help make this error go away?

Comment: You are never changing `head` in the `while` loop, so it never terminates.

Comment: i guess inside your `while` loop, it's `head = newNode.next;` instead of `newNode = newNode.next;`?

Answer (score 0):

As the people in the comments said, you are never changing `head` inside your while loop. Look at your condition: `head!= null`. Assuming this is initially true (so the loop starts running), unless you change `head` inside the loop its state will never change, so the result of your loop condition will not change, hence your loop will never terminate. This infinite loop contains recursive calls to your function, hence your stack overflow exception.

Try changing `newNode = newNode.next` to `head = head.next` so you are actually updating the value of `head`. Or you could try changing your loop condition to `newNode != null`.

Answer (score 0):

change condition in while loop

```
newNode = head;
    while (newNode != null) {
        ....
        newNode = newNode.next;  
    }
```